# How to install ROM and Gapps through Adb & Fastboot without TWRP support?

Tags: adb, custom-roms, installation, fastboot

I have a **Motorola One Macro**, I leave the **firmaware** for you to see what it is,

https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/moto/lima/official/

I want to install a **ROM** according to this site: https://www.getdroidtips.com/android-10-motorola-one-macro/

However, there is no TWRP for this version of Smartphone.

The question is how to install ROM and Gapps through Adb & Fastboot?

Comment: If I get it correctly your device is a MediaTek based device. Those devices are usually flashed in "off-state" via USB using a special MediaTek flash software on the PC.